# How to get output of a Lisp program into Python?

Tags: python, lisp, common-lisp, executable, ccl

I've got a very large Lisp project whose output I'd like to programmatically pipe to a Python program, i.e. use Python to call the Lisp program on some input and get the output back into Python.

The project only compiles in Clozure Common Lisp (ccl64) and I did try to find a way to turn it into an executable (I'm using Mac OS X), but that ran into a lot of dead ends (I am not a Lisp programmer).

This documentation for Clozure Common Lisp should provide the solution to the above, but I was not able to understand it.  The examples I made created a file, but Terminal would not run them as executables.

[How to create executable for ccl64](http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter4.9.html)

I tried to follow this question's answer [Compiling Common Lisp to an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171849/compiling-common-lisp-to-an-executable) except using ccl64's save application function.

```
$ ccl64
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.9-dev-r15612M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)!
? (in-package :ccl)  
#<Package "CCL">
? (defun main () (print "hello"))
MAIN
? (save-application "hello" :toplevel-function #'main)
```

I am trying to use Python's subprocess to invoke ccl64, run the Lisp program, and get the output.  However, subprocess for some reason refuses to run the ccl64 command.  Here is what I wrote so far:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['ccl64', '-h'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

The variable `out` should contain the output of getting the usage/help from ccl64.  Instead I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sub.py", line 3, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(['ccl64', '-h'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I get Python to invoke ccl64 and get output from the Lisp project?

Comment: Specify the full path to the ccl64 binary.

Comment: To extend a bit what @LePetitPrince says: When you're typing on a terminal, typing just `ccl64` works because the executable is in your `PATH` environment variable but (by default), `subprocess` doesn't know that `PATH`. Find where the `ccl64` executable lives and pass the whole path to your `Popen` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in your Python code is clear: No such file or directory.

You need to tell in your Python code which application you want to run in a way that it actually finds it.

It's also not clear why you save a Lisp executable somewhere named `hello`, but you are not trying to call it. With the necessary path. Your code tries to call Clozure CL - without the necessary path - but why? You just saved an executable. Why would you call Clozure CL to run it? I would also save the executable with **prepending the kernel** - that makes it self-contained.

**Example:**

Calling Clozure CL:

```
rjmba:~ joswig$ ccl
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.9-dev-r15612M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)!
```

Defining the `main` function:

```
? (defun main () (print "hello"))
MAIN
```

Saving an executable:

```
? (save-application "hello" :toplevel-function #'main :prepend-kernel t)
```

Running the new executable from the same directory:

```
rjmba:~ joswig$ ./hello

"hello"
```

**Calling a Clozure CL application with an argument:**

```
bash-3.2$ ccl
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.9-dev-r15612M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)!
```

The function `ccl::command-line-arguments` returns the arguments as a list. The first item is the called application itself.

```
? (defun main ()                                                                
    (print (second (ccl::command-line-arguments))))
MAIN

? (save-application "hello"                                                     
                    :toplevel-function #'main                                   
                    :prepend-kernel t)
```

Calling it:

```
bash-3.2$ ./hello hello!

"hello!"
```

Comment: I made the executable with Clozure CL, but when I go to the terminal and enter `hello` (the name of the file created), the terminal does not run it.

Comment: That works.  However when I run my executable, it crashes and then launches the ccl64 repl, frozen in it.  The main function is simply `(defun main (string) (my-fun string))`.

Comment: This function works: `(defun main ()
 (print "hi")
 (quit))`.  I turned it into an executable called `hi`.  But suppose I wish to print an arbitrary string.  How can I make it so when I type `./hi hello!`, the console prints `hello!`.

Comment: I think this global value is what I need to use: `*command-line-argument-list*`.