# Running Lisp program with Python2 or 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, common-lisp

I am having the lisp code that I found at the repository: https://github.com/JafferWilson/test-program
I am looking for compiling and running this code using the python code.
How can I make it possible? I have looked around but didn't find anything related.
Kindly, help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221781/how-to-get-output-of-a-lisp-program-into-python ?

Comment: you might want to try Hy (lisp to python compiler): https://github.com/hylang/hy

Comment: @TarasMatsyk Sorry but how you recoomend the link as I could not understand how to make it possible? Can you please explain that as an answer. If possible show me what need to be done to implement my lisp code.

Comment: Please elaborate, it is not clear at all what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I actually want to use python for running the Lisp program. This is was I want to achieve. As you see the repository is in Lisp and I wantt to run it using the python. If possible compile run evertything.

Comment: Two possible reasons to do this is either because you prefer language a but language b has a neat library you would like to access OR you have your program in language a but the tools don't compile to the target plattform and language b does. If it's the first you can switch it around and do python in CL with https://common-lisp.net/project/clpython/

Comment: I had a brief look at the repository and it appears to be Common Lisp. I think what you should do is run the Lisp program as a separate program. To do this you'll need to install a Common Lisp implementation (e.g. Sbcl) and then you can run the Lisp program like you would run any other process from python. If you want to pass data in and out of the Common Lisp program you may need to set up some serialisation/deserialisation and processing via I/O mechanisms to communicate with python